# Get all classes with an annotation and add them to a hashMap in android

Tags: java, android, hashmap, annotations

I am not sure if this is possible or not, but I would basically like to be able to easily add new items to a list, just by adding a class with a special annotation. The only example I can think of is kind of what I am currently working on. There are a bunch of "challenges" that a user can complete, currently I have a package in my app for the "challenges" and I would like to be able to just create a new class in that package, give it an annotation with some values, like...

```
@Challenge(key="new_challenge")
public class NewChallenge extends Achievement {... }
```

That key would be different for each challenge, it will be the challenge name, then in my code I would like to be able to add them all to a HashMap with that "key" as the hashmap key, so it would be map.add(*annotationkey*, *class*); It sounds like it should be possible and doable. I am wondering, if it's possible, if it's the right way to go about doing it, and how can it be done?

EDIT1
I was able to get the Reflections implemented with gradle, but it is always coming up as empty. There are no annotations found at all. Here is how I have it..

Challenge.java

```
package com.test.annotationtest.annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Challenge {
  public String key();
}
```

Then for one of my challenges I have...
TestChallenge.java

```
package com.test.annotationtest.challenges

import com.test.annotationtest.R;
import com.test.annotationtest.annotation.Challenge;

@Challenge(key="test_challenge")
public class TestChallenge extends Achievement {
  public String name = "Test Challenge";
  public TestChallenge() {}
}
```

Then in my main activity I have...
MainActivity.java

```
package com.test.annotationtest;
import...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  public Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.test"); // have tried "com.test.annotationtest" and "com.test.annotationtest.challenges"
  public static Map<String, Achievement> achievements;
  public static List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    achievements = getClasses();
    //setup recycler view and all that to show achievements
  }

  public Map<String, Achievement> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> challengeClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Challenge.class);
    Log.d("Main Activity", "The Challenges");
    Log.d("MAin Activity", "How many are there? " + Integer.toString(challengeClasses.size());
    //more processing on them;
  }
}
```

but every time I run the application on my emulator it shows in the logcat..
Main Activity: The Challenges
MAin Activity: How many are there? 0

I have 9 classes in the challenges package all annotated with the @Challenge(key="name") in them, but none of them are showing up with the reflections getTypesAnnotatedWith return. The "name" is different for each one. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Create a annotation class ( using `public @interface `)  with `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME` . Then you can get all classes by package levels and getAnnotations on those classes to read your annotation and proceed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create your own annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Challenge {
    public String key() default "";

}
```

Then you may use [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) to get all annotated classes.

```
Set<Class<?>> challengeClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Challenge.class);
```

Then you can extract your key by:

```
String key = challengeClass.getAnnotation(Challenge.class).key();
```

But be advised that reflections should be used carefully and only if really necessary. You are losing control of your code correctness by using it.

**Example:**

***com.test.webapp.Main***

```
package com.test.testapp;

import com.test.testapp.annotations.Challenge;
import org.reflections.Reflections;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.test.testapp");

        Set<Class<?>> challengeClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Challenge.class);
        Map challengeClassesMap = challengeClasses.stream().collect(
                                                            Collectors.toMap(
                                                                    challengeClass -> challengeClass.getAnnotation(Challenge.class).key(),
                                                                    Main::createNewInstanceOfClass
                                                            )
        );

        challengeClassesMap.forEach(
                (key, challengeClass) -> System.out.println(key + " = " + challengeClass.toString())
        );
    }

    private static <T> T createNewInstanceOfClass(Class<T> someClass) {
        try {
            return someClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null; //Bad idea but now it's waste of time
        }
    }
}
```

***com.test.testapp.annotations.Challenge***

```
package com.test.testapp.annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Challenge {
    public String key();
}
```

***com.test.testapp.challenges.SomeChallenge***

```
package com.test.testapp.challenges;

import com.test.testapp.annotations.Challenge;

@Challenge(key = "some_challenge")
public class SomeChallenge {
    public String name = "Some Challenge";

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SomeChallenge{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

***com.test.testapp.challenges.AnotherChallenge***

```
package com.test.testapp.challenges;

import com.test.testapp.annotations.Challenge;

@Challenge(key = "another_challenge")
public class AnotherChallenge {
    public String name = "Another Challenge";

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AnotherChallenge{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

***pom.xml dependency (I'm using Maven)***

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.11</version>
</dependency>
```

***Output***

```
some_challenge = SomeChallenge{name='Some Challenge'}
another_challenge = AnotherChallenge{name='Another Challenge'}
```

I have no more code. Directories are same as packages.

Comment: B-E-A-utiful !!!! Thank you sir. To loop through the Set<Class<?>> challengeClass would I just do something like "for(Class<?> challengeClass : challengeClasses.entrySet()) { ... };"?

Comment: ```Map classesMap = challengeClasses.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                cl -> cl.getAnnotation().key(),
                cl -> cl.newInstance()
        ));```
Like Java 8 way. This should work. Maybe you'll have to handle some exceptions, I don't remember.

Comment: I hate to bother, but could you please take a look at the edit I made and see if you can see why they aren't showing up when using getTypesAnnotatedWith(Challenge.class) method. Thank you

Comment: I realized I made a mistake. It should be: ```cl.getAnnotation(Challenge.class).key()```.
But to be honest I don't really know how to help you this time. I've just made a similar example and worked as well:
```Reflections ref = new Reflections("com.test");
        Set<Class<?>> set = ref.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Challenge.class);
        System.out.println(set);```
Result: ```[class com.test.A]```

Comment: Works also with more classes. Maybe someone else will spot the problem.

Comment: I know this may be asking a little much, but I am just not getting it to work. Do you think you could upload a working example somewhere and I can see if I can find what I'm doing wrong. The documentation for that is kind of confusing. If not I understand, gotta try right? Thank you

Comment: I added my own example. (Please, stack community, don't blame for wall of text).
It runs perfectly for me.

Comment: It won't work because Reflections doesn't work on Android :(

Comment: `Reflections` is no longer in active development or maintainence. The last release was Oct 2021.