# Calling mulitple classes' method inside a package

Tags: java, package

I am writing a Minecraft mod. I've got multiple classes inside a package, which all have the `public static register()` method. Upon starting of the Minecraft Client, I am calling every classes' `register()` method.

There are two problems with my code:

1. There are a lot of classes inside that package and having every single class inside the main class looks awful
2. Adding new class inside the package does not automatically add the `register()`-part inside the main class and can be easily forgotten.

The question is now: is there any way to automatically call every classes' `register()` method inside the main class?

One of my ideas was to fetch every class inside the package using `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream` and then `Class.forName`, which looks like an overkill to me.

I have never actually learned java and only got to know it through examples, so don't go too hard on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own annotation `@ToRegister` and use it in your classes:

```java
@ToRegister
public class ToRegister1 {
}
```

Then use [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) to find the classes  [as explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50955914/11197189).

Comment: This has been in the list of my ideas, but I was not too familiar with annotations. Thanks for the links, now I got a better insight